# MySQL: Update multiple columns in IF statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update several columns in case one new value is lower than the old one:

```
INSERT INTO `toptimes`.`$enc` (serial,name,time,date,tag) VALUES ('$serial','$name','$time','$date','$tag') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IF(`time` > '$time',(`time` = '$time',`name`='$name'));
```

Here comes the problem, I need to make it like that:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE IF(`time` > '$time',(`time` = '$time',`name`='$name'));
```

So, if new `$time` value is lower than the old `time`, update 2 columns: update `time` and also update `name` column, but if the case doesn't match, update nothing. How can I make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` expressions in the `on duplicate key part`.  You just have to repeat the logic:

```
INSERT INTO `toptimes`.`$enc` (serial, name, time, date, tag)
    VALUES ('$serial', '$name', '$time', '$date', '$tag')
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        time = least(time, values(time)),
        name = (case when values(time) < time then values(name) else name end);
```

Comment: The problem is, it chooses the greatest value when it should choose the least one, and name still does not update as i remake it:

INSERT INTO `toptimes`.`$enc` (serial,name,time,date,tag) VALUES ('$serial','$name','$time','$date','$tag') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time = LEAST('$time',`time`), name = (CASE WHEN time < VALUES(time) THEN '$name' ELSE `name` END);

Comment: @Gallardo994 . . . `VALUES(time)` is the *new* value of time being inserted, equivalent to `$time` in your case.  `VALUES()` has several advantages, among them, you can insert multiple rows at the same time.

Comment: is there any other way of formulating SQL statements to avoid repeating the logic?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by moving `time` update to the end:

```
INSERT INTO `toptimes`.`$enc` (serial,name,time,date,tag) VALUES ('$serial','$name','$time','$date','$tag') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = (CASE WHEN '$time' < `time` THEN '$name' ELSE `name` END), time = LEAST('$time',`time`);
```